# Can a child element in Android ignore its containing style?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a containing LinearLayout which has a style associated with it that gives the container 20dp of padding.  This is great for 99% of the elements contained inside.  There may be 1 element which I'd like to have extend across the screen (android:layout_width="match_parent") and ignore the padding set by the containing LinearLayout.  Is this possible?  Or, do I need to remove the style from the containing LinearLayout and apply it to every other element individually?

(some attributes excluded for brevity)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Would like this to ignore padding, extend fully. -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtExperienceTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/sub_header_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can't really pick and choose like that. I'd remove the padding from the LinearLayout and apply `margin` to the children.

To expand on what loeschg said in the comment below, I'd recommend using a "child style". Since it looks like each child will only need left/right margins, it will save some typing and look cleaner to just have one line on each child, rather than setting both left and right separately on each.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this, either. I think what @Geobits said is correct. Adding on to what he said, I'd suggest creating a dimens file that holds the specific dimensions values (similar to Strings.xml) if you haven't already and use that value in xml. It at least will allow you follow some DRY principles.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach out of the container. Apply a `style` to the elements rather than the container if you have an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Yes It will ignore it, the layout that you wrote is something like this.

General thinking

```
int x = 7;
x = 20;

Show me that x = 7; ---You wanted to do something like this whit your layout
```

> 

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- Would like this to ignore padding, extend fully. -->
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtExperienceTitle"
    style="@style/sub_header_title" // --- Style before adding laout_width if you want the layout to be match_parent
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```